# Why does this call to arrow (->) operator fail?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider the following code :

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() : a{ 0 }
    {}

    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "a : " << a << std::endl;
    }

    void operator->()
    {
        a = 5;
    }

    void operator++()
    {
        ++a;
    }

public:
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    Test a;
    a.print();

    // Increment operator
    a.operator++();      // CORRECT
    ++a;                 // CORRECT
    a.print();

    // Indirection operator
    a.operator->();      // CORRECT
    a->;                 // INCORRECT
    a.print();
}
```

Why is the call to the second `->` operator incorrect? I know this usage of `->` is different from the general usage, but is such usage disallowed by the standard?

Comment: Added to my list of things I never f'ing thought about before. Thanks for that. =P

Comment: Might be somewhat intuitive to think of `a.operator->()` as a function call, while `a->` as syntactic sugar for `(*a).`

Comment: `a->;` is a syntax error. Operator overloading cannot create new syntax, it just provides different behaviour for existing syntax

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sub-section on **Class member access** from **Overloaded Operators** from CPP  standard draft (N4713) states this:

> **16.5 Overloaded operators**
>   ...
>   **16.5.6 Class member access [over.ref]**
>   1. `operator->` shall be a non-static member function taking no parameters. It implements the class member access syntax that uses `->`.
>
> ```
> postfix-expression -> template(opt) id-expression //This!!
> postfix-expression -> pseudo-destructor-name
> ```
>
> An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (16.3).

As you can see the `id-expression` is very much needed if the `->` operator is overloaded.

Answer (score 6):

[Class member access [expr.ref/1] §7.6.1.5/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#1):

> 1. A postfix expression followed by a dot `.` or an arrow `->`, optionally followed by the keyword *template* ([temp.names]), **and then followed by an *id-expression***, is a postfix expression. **The postfix expression** before the dot or arrow is evaluated; the result of that evaluation, **together with the *id-expression*, determines the result of the entire postfix expression**.

[Names [expr.prim.id] (§7.5.4)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id):

> id-expression:
>   unqualified-id
>   qualified-id
>
> 1. An id-expression is a restricted form of a primary-expression. [ Note: An id-expression can appear after . and -> operators. — end note ]
> 2. An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
>    2.1. as part of a class member access in which the object expression refers to the member's class or a class derived from that class, or
>      2.2. to form a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]), or
>      2.3. if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.

Answer (score 1):

As said by M.M, `a->;` is a *sintax error*. A non-static member operator function *without* argument is a prefix (as `operator++()`; postfix is `operator++(int))` `a.operator->();` would be `->a;` (wow!), but this is *again* a sintax error. The standard specifies the fine details...